# ng-attr-aria-live (or aria-live) does not work in the latest chrome(Version 69.0.3497.100) with mac (high sierra version 10.13.2) voiceover

Tags: angularjs, macos, google-chrome, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `span` tag with `ng-attr-aria-live` and uses `ng-if` to be added conditionally but the voiceover does not detect that `aria-live` even though I see the `span` tag being popped into the DOM. The same code worked before with the last chrome and voiceover but it does not work anymore after the update.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this issue or at least experience this? And is there any way to work around this?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of span use a div with aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" also modify the CSS to keep UI intact.

Comment: didn't do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Chrome reads/re-reads the data whenever aria-label property is changed on the focused element. Hence, make sure aria-label property gets updated. Also, in your case, please try to wrap that span with another span and add aria-live property to that and make sure aria-label gets updated for inner-span.